Theme extending Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar uses colors from values-night folder
My app has two themes:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
<style name="AppTheme.DayNight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

My device is set to night mode and activities using the first theme are using colors from the values-night. How is that possible? Shouldn't the non-DayNight theme completely ignore night resources?
I know I can set AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO) in my app, but I'm wondering why this is happening.
